# Cast timestamp from ms to string format in Hive 3.1.3

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to convert a milliseconds timestamp into string format while keeping the ms part.
Code below:

select from_unixtime(cast(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) + regexp_extract(string(current_timestamp),'\.(\d+)$',1) as int), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") as date_formatted_ms

However I am not getting the ms part in a good format: [image]

How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, could not get it. The task is to convert timestamp to string preserving milliseconds? Why don't you just use STRING(current_timestamp)?

Comment: results produced by this query `select current_timestamp as ts_ms, string(current_timestamp) as ts_string`  are always equal but different types: string and timestamp